# Should Views and ViewGroups conventionally be declared as instance or local variables in Activities?

Tags: java, android, view, viewgroup

It doesn't seem as intuitive to decide which variables should be instance variables and which should be locally declared in classes that extend `Activity` to me as for other types of objects.

For classes that DO extend Activity, where do you declare the `Views` and `ViewGroups`, assuming declaring them both in the onCreate() method and as instance variables works. Which is the convention?

Comment: Keep them member if you need to access in multiple unrelated methods (to avoid multiple expensive findViewById calls), local otherwise. Simple as that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So classes that extend Activity aren't like the everyday objects we deal with where it's pretty easy to distinguish which variables should be instance variables and which should be locally declared.

Sure they are. Declare them where you need them. If you only need to access them in certain methods to say set text or something then declare them there. If you need them in multiple methods then declare them as member variables.

> assuming declaring them both in the onCreate() method and as instance variables works.

Why would you declare them in two places?

> Which is the convention?

See the first part of this answer. Typically I declare them as member variables and initialize them in `onCreate()` because I seem to need them in multiple places and I like having them in one place.

Just make sure you initialize them *after* calling `setContentView()` or they will be `null`.

Comment: I didn't mean declaring them in both places; I meant in either... as in where do you declare it when declaring it in `onCreate()` or as an instance variable works either way. You answered this though.

Comment: Ok, glad I could answer it. `onCreate()` is like any other method in that if you declare it there it will be local to that method.

Answer (score 1):

`Activity` in `Android` represents part of `UI` object, lets say `"window"`.
Activity has some components - layout with `Views`.

If you want to use your views in many methods of your `activity` class then declare them as instance variables. Because finding them with `findViewById` will be done only once. And then you can use them many times just by using instance variables.

If you make your views references local their scopes will be narrowed.

Comment: What about when you don't need to use their references in other methods? Would you still declare them as instance variables?

Comment: If you don't want to use them in other methods so use it once locally in onCreate. Simple.
You need to choose solution which is good for you;)

Answer (score 0):

If the activity holds the Views/View groups it's recommended to declare them as private members in the activity class.

Simply as is :)